# checking information from Database

Tags: php

I'm Trying To Let users Login

on control page:

```
<?php include"files/header.php";?>
<?php
global $tf_handle;
$u_name  = strip_tags($_POST['u_name']);    
$u_pass  = md5($_POST['u_pass']);       
if(isset($_POST['login']))
{
    if(empty($u_name) or empty($u_pass))
    {
        echo"
            <div class='error'>Fill the The Form PLease</div><br />
            ";      
    }
    else
    {
        $sqlquery = mysqli_query($tf_handle,"SELECT * FROM user WHERE u_name = '".$u_name."' AND u_pass = '".$u_pass."'");
        if(mysqli_num_rows($sqlquery) > 0)
        {
            $fetchLquery = mysqli_fetch_object($sqlquery);
            print_r($fetchLquery);
            $uid = $fetchLquery->u_id;
            $uname = $fetchLquery->u_name;
            echo "$uname";
            $upass = $fetchLquery->u_pass;
            if($uname != $u_name )
            {
                //AND $upass != $u_pass
                echo"
                <div class='error'>wrong name</div><br />
                ";  
            }
            else
            {
                setcookie("uid",$uid,time()+60*60*24);
                setcookie("login",1,time()+60*60*24);
                echo"
                <div class='error'>Done !</div><br />
                ";
                header('Refresh: 3;url=index.php'); 
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo"
                <div class='error'>Wrong information</div><br />
                ";              
        }
    }
}
?>  
            <div class="rightco">
            <div class="B_t_in">    
                    <div class="title_b">
                        <h3>Pen Testing</h3>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="info">
                        By : ~Hacker~
                        Date :30/5/2015  
                    </div>
            </div>  


                <table class="tb" width="100%" border="0" >
                    <tr>
                        <td width="20%"><div class="pic"><img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-xUY6gP4Uhgw/U7ADSxKjwBI/AAAAAAAABM8/uVAbk_D06Wg/s1600/php-framework1+copy.png" alt="" /></div> </td>
                        <td width="80%">
                            <p>
                                Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test TestTest Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Tes
                                Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test
                            </p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>   
                </table>

                <div class="more"><a href="#">Read More !</a></div>

            </div>
<?php include"files/block.php";?>
<?php include"files/footer.php";?>
```

The Result is

Wrong Name

& i tried to echo the Variables to check it

```
$fetchLquery  = stdClass Object ( [u_id] => 3 [u_name] => memo [u_pass] => 202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70 [u_email] => jankeh@yahoo.com [u_ulv] => 1 )

$uname = 'memo'
```

This condition `if($uname != $u_name )` shouldn't be executed

i don't know what's the reason of this problem !

i should check another thing ?

Comment: Why shouldn't `if($uname != $u_name )` be executed? or Do you mean it shouldn't be true?

Comment: I'm on to another thread, you are open to SQL injections with your current code. Also login credentials shouldn't be client side, use `$_SESSION`.

Comment: i mean $uname already = $u_name so the condition shouldn't be executed and else condition should execute

Comment: i use session but this time i'm trying to do like tutorial and in the online  tutorial instructor used set cookies

Comment: var_dump the two values. Are they actually the same? With cookie approach any user can make a cookie named login with the value of `1` and BAM access. Also if they are able to obtain another user's ID they can become that user.

Comment: it will be fixed in the rest of the tutorial my problem is why the condition works and it's something like 1 != 1 -_-

Comment: Please update your question I can't tell exactly what that is....wasn't there just code in your comment? Without outputting the actual results of the variables it is hard to say what is happening..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89099/discussion-between-smile-and-chris85).

Comment: I suspect you have case-insensitive collation on the table. So MySQL is comparing case-insensitively, but PHP is case-sensitive.

Comment: Use `var_dump($u_name, $uname)`.

Comment: This was resolved in a chat. The issue was the username in DB had a space and PHP didn't.

Comment: You really shouldn't use MD5 password hashes and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to be checking if the names match anyway.

Why?

Your query will only return data if the username and password match those that you have put into the query. You're doing the same thing twice - once in SQL and again in PHP!

You just need to check if anything has been returned from the query. If it has, you know it's a match! :)

Comment: True, but aside from being redundant there's nothing wrong with it. Code should still work. Current issue why is SQL seeing the usernames as the same and PHP as different?

Comment: As I typed the answer I was thinking to myself 'Should I say this? It isn't strictly answering what the user wants'. Just trying to make smile's life easier!

Comment: mfisher i notices that but that problem like what chris85 said

Comment: i changed that condition to    if(1 != 2 )
   {
    //AND $upass != $u_pass
    echo"
       <div class='error'>wrong name</div><br />
    "; 
   } and it executes too !!! that made me crazy

Comment: @smile 1 is not equal to 2, so that **should** execute.

Comment: yes yes i typed it wrong i didn't mean that the error was because of whitespace chri85 really helped me